# quotative と without an accompanying verb?

Tags: grammar, words, particle-と, conditionals

The following is an excerpt from a dialogue between me and my language partner:
「農業を仕事としてする農家の人頭が減っていながら、大型の農場が増えています。」
を、日本の現状からわかりやすく言い替えてみると、

→全体の農家数が減る一方で、大規模農家が増えています。

For context: We were talking about her family which ran a small scale farm back in the day. I told her about the situation in germany, where smaller agricultural business are constantly on the decline, with many farmers reducing their work as a farmer to a sidebusiness.

About the sentence in question:
Doe anyone have an idea why the sentence just ends in "...替えてみると..."? If you think she just forgot to bring the sentence to an end, just tell me and I'll ask  her. However, if such abrupt ellipses are common in japanese, please help me extrapolating what is supposed to stand there ^^

Also, what is this 模 in 大規模農家? Jisho redirects me to "wooden printing block" (形木 ) but that doesnt make much sense here Oo

Comment: http://jisho.org/search/%E5%A4%A7%E8%A6%8F%E6%A8%A1

Comment: Are you using rikaigu or another Japanese dictionary lookup browser extension? I ask because they're good at finding word boundaries, which would have cleared up the 大規模 question. Even if you're not using a browser extension, if you double-click on the word, your OS will probably guess the word boundary correctly.

Comment: @mamster もしかして、rikaigu って、りかいちゃん(りかいくん)のドイツ語版とかですか？

Comment: ああ、rikaiguって、りかいちゃん・くんの三人目の兄弟でしたけど、最近見つかりにくくなったようです。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> quotative と

The と in 言い換えてみる**と** is not a quotative particle, but a conjunctive particle (接続助詞) meaning "When~" or "If~".

> 「言い換えてみる**と**、・・・」 = "*If/When* you rephrase it, ..." "*If/When* you say it in a different way, ..."

She said:

> 「(Original Sentence)」を言い換えてみると、→ 「(Rephrased Sentence)。」
>   "If you rephrase / To rephrase '[Original Sentence]': (you'll get) '[Rephrased Sentence]'."

---

<sub>As for 大規模...

How about using Rikaichan or Rikaikun?</sub>

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

（１）
基本形は次のようになります。

> Ａを、日本の現状からわかりやすく**言い替えてみると**、Ｂ**と言うことができます**。

基本形において
Ａ：「農業を仕事としてする農家の人頭が減っていながら、大型の農場が増えています。」
Ｂ：→全体の農家数が減る一方で、大規模農家が増えています。
そして、
**と言うことができます**が省略されています。

「と言うことができます」の部分は「と言えます」あるいは「となります」と言い換えることはできますが、省略することはあまり勧められません。多分Ｂの最初に「→」があり、最後の部分が「増えています。」のように文が完全に終わった形式になっていますので、作者が本来必要な文言を省略しても良いと判断した、あるいは省略しても良いと錯覚したのだと思いますが、良い文章の書き方とは言えないように思います。

なお、「言い**替**える」は、私は「言い**換**える」と普段書いています。[ここ](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1338699383)では、「言い換える」を勧めています。

（２）「大規模」はLeeboさんのコメントにある通りです。

> 大規模＝大＋規模